# Using macro guards with file names that have underscores?

Tags: c++, guard, convention

I was just wondering, I normally don't use underscores in files. I know that for "camelback" files (`exampleHeader.h`) you do `EXAMPLEHEADER_H`.

Is it the same for file names with words separated by underscores? So `example_header.h` would still be `EXAMPLEHEADER_H`?

Comment: The name of the include guard and the filename don't need to be related at all.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Was totally unsure because I was always taught that they should be the same and the underscore is what threw me off.

Comment: There may be conventions (e.g., http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#The__define_Guard ), but include guards are entirely up to you.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Like I said before, wasn't exactly sure.